# Mudblazor clear TextField after "Enter"

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I am using Mudblazor component TextField in my Blazor Server project.

I want to clear the TextField after I press "Enter"

Here is my code in my **Index.Razor** :

@page :

```
<MudTextField class="pa-4" @bind-Value="newTodayTask" Clearable="true"
OnKeyUp="AddTodayTask" Adornment="Adornment.End" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Outlined.Add"
FullWidth="false" Placeholder="Create a new task here, press Enter ↵ to save" Variant="Variant.Text" 
Style="width:600px; margin-bottom:10px"></MudTextField>
```

@code :

```
public string newTodayTask { get; set; }

protected async Task AddTodayTask(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == "Enter")
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodayTask))
        {
            var result = false;                
            var todaytask = new TodayTaskModel { TaskName = newTodayTask, DueDate = dueDate, TaskCreatedBy = taskCreatedBy};
            result = await Service.CreateTodayTask(todaytask);
            StateHasChanged();
            newTodayTask = string.Empty;

        }

    }
    OnInitialized();  
}
```

I already try with *string.Empty;* and *StateHasChanged();* but still not works.

I really appreciate any help that can provide. Thanks

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to clear test on pressing enter? What about to do a `EditForm`, enter is default key for `Submit`.

Comment: @daniherrera Thanks for your reply, so I need to put this MudTextField inside a Mudform?

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to handle submission on Mudform. I posted a sample using EditForm as I commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On some platforms, hitting the "enter" key while a text control is focused implicitly submits the form, the **[implicit submission](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#implicit-submission)** pattern.

Because your form only has one input element, maybe, the most elegant solution is to use this pattern as UX for your data entry. You should to think on **accessibility**.

I post a sample in [try.mudblazor](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mkGwEpbUQyHVPyrg):

[image]

The source code:

```
<MudPaper Class="pa-4">
    <EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
        <MudTextField 
            @bind-Value="@model.Name" 
            Immediate="true" 
            Label="Some Text and press enter" />
    </EditForm>
</MudPaper>

<ul>
@foreach(var s in history)
{
    <li>@s</li>
}
</ul>

@code { 
    public class MyTask
    {
        public string Name {get; set;} = default!;
    }
    
    List<string> history = new List<string>();

    MyTask model =  new MyTask(){Name="hi"};

    private void OnValidSubmit()
    {
        history.Add(model.Name);
        model.Name = "";
        StateHasChanged();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find this and other examples  by following the path **MudBlazor/src/MudBlazor.UnitTests.Viewer/TestComponents/TextField/**
https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor

This code ***.razor** for you:

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="value" 
              Immediate="true" OnKeyDown="OnKeyDown" 
              Label="Hit Enter to Clear" 
              TextUpdateSuppression="false">
</MudTextField>
<br>
<span>value: @(value)</span>

@code {
  string value;

  async void OnKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs args) 
  {
    if (args.Key=="Enter") 
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        value = "";
        StateHasChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Anyone finding this after today you need the TextUpdateSuppression=false on the MudTextInput control

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution that does not suffer from the character-swallowing bug that a permanent `TextUpdateSuppression=true` results in. Dynamically disabling the property and resetting it after a short delay did the trick. I am using MudBlazor but assumes this works with a regular Blazor component.

```
<MudTextField @ref="RefEntryField" @bind-Value="TextChatValue" Immediate="true" OnKeyDown="OnTextChatSend" />
```

```
@code {
    private MudTextField<string> RefEntryField;
    private string _textChatValue;
}
```

```
private async Task OnTextChatSend(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Key is "Enter" or "NumppadEnter")
        {
            RefEntryField.TextUpdateSuppression = false;
            
            // Process input, etc.

            TextChatValue = string.Empty;
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(150);
                RefEntryField.TextUpdateSuppression = true;
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing towards the right direction @StageCodes. I was going nuts until I finally stepped into the code for the `TextUpdateSuppression` parameter where I found this gem:

> When TextUpdateSuppression is true (which is default) the text can not be updated by bindings while the component is focused in BSS (not WASM). This solves issue #1012: Textfield swallowing chars when typing rapidly If you need to update the input's text while it is focused you can set this parameter to false. Note: on WASM text update suppression is not active, so this parameter has no effect.

The link to the respective source code is https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/blob/dev/src/MudBlazor/Base/MudBaseInput.cs#L190.

Long story short, I think your approach is the way to go but it can be a bit optimized to the following code. The delay is a bit of a dirty hack, I think it is better to put it in the `OnAfterRederAsync()` method.

```
<MudTextField @ref="RefEntryField" @bind-Value="TextChatValue"
    Immediate="true" OnKeyDown="OnTextChatSend" />

@code {
    private MudTextField<string>? RefEntryField;
    private string _textChatValue;
}

private void OnTextChatSend(KeyboardEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Key is not "Enter" or "NumpadEnter")
        return;

    RefEntryField!.TextUpdateSuppression = false;
    TextChatValue = string.Empty;
    StateHasChanged();
}

protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (RefEntryField != null)
        RefEntryField.TextUpdateSuppression = true;
        
    return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

This is still quite cumbersome especially if you have several input fields and need to keep references to all of them and I am not very happy with the amount of code for such a simple solution. But I suppose that is the trade-off for using a framework and the best solution to this exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found more elegant solution. Digging the source code I found that in SSR mode inputs are updated only when they are not focused. So I tried calling `BlurAsync()` method before updating input value and then bringing focus back by calling `FocusAsync()` method. `StateHasChanged()` must also be called after updating input value to trigger rendering.

```
    <MudTextField @ref="InputFieldRef"
     ...
    </MudTextField>

    OnSubmit()
    {
        await InputFieldRef!.BlurAsync();
        Input = "";
        StateHasChanged();
        await InputFieldRef!.FocusAsync();
    }
```