Blazor Server - MudBlazor - MudTextField bind value not updating
The MudTextField is bound to variable chatInput.  Once user inputs their query and hits Enter, HandleKeyUp() is called.  In that method, we grab the value of the query and then clear the field and attempt to update the state.  The variable bound to the field changes to an empty value in debug, however the UI does not clear the text.  We want the text clear, so the user can more easily type another query there.
Tech Stack:  Blazor Server, MudBlazor, C#.
// Clear the input
   chatInput = string.Empty;
  
// Trigger UI update to clear the input field
   await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

//Part of the MudBlazor element
 MudTextField @bind-Value="chatInput" Placeholder="Type a message"
 @bind-Value:after="@(() => InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged))"  
 @onkeyup="HandleKeyUp"


Sometimes in debug walk through, it does clear the text from the UI after the last line of code executes.  But have only seen this in debug mode, not regular execution.  Even tried creating a new simplified project to test it, same issue.

I was able to work around this going to javascript direct, but would still be nice to know if its possible to get it to work directly with Mud Blazor.

Here's a possible workaround, without javascript. According to the link at the bottom, in server-side rendering, the textfield updates when the input looses focus.
<MudTextField @ref="messageField" @bind-Value="@chatInput" Placeholder="Type a message" OnKeyUp="HandleKeyUp"/>

@code {
    private string chatInput = string.Empty;
    private MudTextField<string> messageField = default!;

    private async Task HandleKeyUp(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == "Enter")
        {
            var result = await SendChatMessage(chatInput);
            if (result)
            {
                await messageField.BlurAsync();
                chatInput = "";
                // Should not be needed to call StateHasChanged from my testing
                // StateHasChanged();
                await messageField.FocusAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    private ValueTask<bool> SendChatMessage(string message)
    {
        // Send message to server
        return ValueTask.FromResult(true);
    }
}

Was struggling myself, but found the workaround here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77290588/3616319

You could use "@ref"."clear()" to clear the bind value.
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<MudTextField @ref="txt1" @bind-Value="chatInput" OnKeyUp="HandleKeyUp"></MudTextField>

@code{
    private MudTextField<string> txt1;
    private string chatInput;

    private void HandleKeyUp(KeyboardEventArgs args){       
        if (args.Key == "Enter")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(chatInput);
            txt1.Clear();
        }
    }
 }

